# How do I accelerate reading large files in GNU Octave?

Tags: csv, octave, large-files

I'm importing a large CSV file into GNU Octave, doing some simple data manipulation and creating some plots. The file has about 6.5 million rows. I expected the process of file reading to take about two to three hours, because that's how long it usually takes to create a file this size in my experience. Added a status counter when it wasn't finishing and found that it was slowing down as it read; after 12 hours, only at line 1.5 million and moving at a crawl. According to Resource Monitor, though, no memory issues. Is there a more efficient way to read the code than what I have below? Do I need to do something special to allocate memory to the process so it doesn't slow down? This is the loop that's reading in the CSV. It's a while loop that scans the csv one line at a time, extracts the columns I need and ends when it reaches the first blank line:

```
% Process File
  F=1;
  while 1
    % Status Counter
        printf ("Status: %d \r", F);
        fflush (stdout);
        F=F+1;
    % Read first unread line
        line = fgetl(fileID);
    % Exit while loop if line is empty
        if ~ischar(line)
          break;
        endif
    % Translate Line
        Bank = textscan (line, '%f',  'Delimiter', ',');
        Bank = cell2mat (Bank);
        Bank = transpose (Bank);
    % Append Bank to Output
      Output = [Output; Bank(1, 1:9), Bank(1, 13:14), Bank(1, 20:21)];
  endwhile
```

Comment: file structure ? header or not ? what is the problem in using dlmread https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFdlmread ?

Comment: @matzeri I got used to doing it this way because I deal with a lot of irregular files, but this file is numeric only, doesn't have a header row and has a consistent number of entries per row. Would dlm read be faster, though? I thought this was a pretty minimal set of instructions. I'll give it a try and add a note if that also doesn't help.

Comment: it is a loop, by definition loop are slow on interpreted language

Comment: @matzeri can't flag as an answer, but this is working much better. Thank you.

Comment: @TonyBullard, make sure you pay attention to Chris's answer below, though. most likely your original code would have been tolerable without the repeated copying/appending.  If you have non-numeric code and need to do this where dlmread doesn't work, that will be important.

Comment: btw, when you have irregular data you can use `csv2cell` from the io package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the slow part:

```
Output = [Output; Bank(1, 1:9), Bank(1, 13:14), Bank(1, 20:21)];
```

What you do here is create a new matrix, copy `Output` and the new row into it, and assign it to `Output`. As `Output` becomes larger, the copy becomes increasingly expensive.

What you need to do is preallocate the output array. Always preallocate!